# Simplifying JSP code

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Tools and technologies used: `JEE, EJB, MVC(servlets + JSP's), JPA, MySQL, TomEE server, Eclipse IDE`.

I have a `JSP` that is pretty long, and asking for advice how should i put some parts of this `JSP` page to separate place, and just call that (object, or whatever) in `JSP`.

Actually, I am reading some data from database in `ServletContextListener` and store those data ( in a `list`) in `servlet context`. Then in `JSP` I am creating menu items by reading that data. So, I am using several nested `JSTL foreach` loops and `if statements` to retrieve the data from the list. All this is generating `JSP` markup under `<nav>` tag.

So, I wonder is there a way to separate this part somewhere, and just call it in `JSP`? (to make it more object oriented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move things, which repeat inside your JSP, into a separate file and include it in the main JSP with `<jsp:include page="relativeUrl" />`

A second option is when you write you own Tag-library, which might become closer to OO-Style.

Comment: Thanks for help, `<jsp:include/>` is just what fits

Answer (score 1):

@Spindizzy's answer is the best to answer your immediate question, but my recommendation is that you look into a MVC framework like JSF.  As your application grows, it will become very difficult to maintain.  If you are working in an environment which restricts the libraries you can use, or you don't want lots of JAR file dependencies to manage, JSF is a good choice because it comes with all major Java-EE compliant application servers.

Comment: I have to use plain MVC for this application. It is simple project, but I made this JSP complicated so looking for how to parse it. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Comment: I understand.  If you need to Google for further information, look for "Model 2 MVC JSP", which is what this methodology was called in the pre-JSF days.  There should be some tips available that may help with this method of coding.

Comment: I see. Can you please confirm if I am correct: My `JSP` page follows `HTML5` standards (header tag, nav tag, aside tag, footer tag...). And those same tags repeats through several different `JSP` pages. Is it smart to each of these tags put in separate `JSP`, and include it in main `JSP`? So, basicly only main content of the `JSP`  will change, and other parts would be imported(included).

Comment: That would be the easiest way.  The other thing that you could do is use HTML5 itself to include whatever functionality, but the jsp:include method will save you roundtrips.